# What Programming Language is Google's Nexus One Using?

Tags: android, nexus-one

Is it just Java?

Comment: It looks like the SO tag "nexus" refers to something else. Maybe we should make a "nexus-one" tag?

Comment: Doesn't the 'android' tag hint at a question _about_ Android, not one whose answer is Android?

Comment: You can also just program using Javascript & HTML5. That's the way I roll.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/) is Java-based.

I am sure there is some ARM-assembly, C and C++ in the mix too for the low level stuff.

Comment: sweet. once i finish my iPhone App I'm jumping over to the Android ;)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you program in Java, but you can also program in native C with the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html#overview).

Answer (score 3):

Remember though, that even though you write Android apps in Java, the code is not compiled to normal Java bytecode. It is instead compiled to Dalvik vm code. This means that you can't use common third party JAR files that are Java bytecode class files.

Comment: But you could if you had the original .java files, right?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article on the Dalvik VM, there's a tool to convert Java class files to the Dalvik format, so I imagine you could convert a whole compiled JAR.

Comment: Yes, you can convert jars to dalvik.

Answer (score 1):

Android 2.1 SDK - Java

Comment: It should be noted that Android is not Java. It uses the Java programming language, there is a huge difference. To call something Java implies that it is a sanctioned VM and will run other Java applications, which Android will not. They simply use their compiler/vm to build and run apps written in the Java programming language.

Comment: You're rather overstating the case.  J2ME phones don't run any java application either, they're a different platform (albeit a Sun-sanctioned one).  Android is no different; it has its own platform library, but the core Java API remains unchanged.  And FWIW, it doesn't use the Sun JVM, but Google's own (Dalvik), which has its own bytecode architecture and converts from Java .class files at build time.  No Sun code exists on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus One uses Android 2.1, and to develop programs for Android, we can use the Java programming language. For advanced usage or more performance, Google provides [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html), where we can use C to write programs.